# How to get XPath from an XML?

Tags: xpath

I have an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <rows>
        <column account="1" name="balibid" seq="1">1</column>
        <column account="1" name="genre" seq="1">Kids</column>
        <column account="1" name="ph" seq="1">3</column>
        <column account="1" name="ph" seq="1">4</column>
        <column account="1" name="ph" seq="1">5</column>
        <column account="1" name="ph" seq="1">6</column>
        <column account="1" name="pl6" seq="1">6</column>
 </rows>
</response>
```

I need XPath of column name = genre. What should I use?

Answer (score 3):

Using `//` in XPATH queries leads to unnecessary (and potentially expensive) evaluation, it's how I started (because it's easy), but I'm now trying hard to kick the habit.

Given you've provided a nice, well formed sample. Here are two example XPATH queries:

```
/response/rows/column[@name="genre"]
```

And

```
rows/column[@name="genre"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
//column[@name='genre']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use** (for the particular provided XML document):

```
/*/*/*[@name = 'genre']
```

**XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*/*[@name = 'genre']"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<response>
    <rows>
        <column account="1" name="balibid" seq="1">1</column>
        <column account="1" name="genre" seq="1">Kids</column>
        <column account="1" name="ph" seq="1">3</column>
        <column account="1" name="ph" seq="1">4</column>
        <column account="1" name="ph" seq="1">5</column>
        <column account="1" name="ph" seq="1">6</column>
        <column account="1" name="pl6" seq="1">6</column>
 </rows>
</response>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected node is copied to the output:**

```
<column account="1" name="genre" seq="1">Kids</column>
```